# Using the Apply construction

Tags: functions, function-construction

I am puzzled about the use of Apply (@@).  Consider

```
g = t;
g1 = Function @@ {t, g} 
g2 = Function[t, g]
```

Why does g2 differ from g1?  I had thought they would be the same.  But they return

```
Function[t, t]
Function[t, g]
```

Comment: Type: `Attributes[Function]` and `Attributes[Apply]` and you will see that only Function has the attribute "HoldAll"

Comment: `Attributes[Function]` will show that `Function` has the attribute `HoldAll`. For `g1`, the arguments are evaluated before `Function` is applied. For `g2` the arguments are held.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html

Comment: Thanks to all for this very helpful discussion.  A corollary is that 
`g2 = Function[t, Evaluate[2 g]];`
also works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an expression, before being evaluated, this...

```
Function @@ {t, g}
```

is actually this...

```
Apply[Function, List[t, g]]
```

Now, we start the evaluation process. The details of the exact sequence aren't all that important, but the arguments get evaluated before the rule for the head gets implemented. So, at some point we get to this...

```
Apply[Function, List[t, t]]
```

because we applied the OwnValues for g. And then so on...

On the other hand,

```
Function[t, g]
```

is sort of static already, because Function has the HoldAll attribute. So, until this expression is fed arguments, it'll just remain in this form.